# Android map only showing tiles

Tags: android, google-maps, grid, maps, tiles

Hi I am new to android programming and I followed the steps from many tutorials, but I only managed to display the google map which only shows tiles both on the emulator and the device. Many thanks in advance!

Heres my Manifest:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bi.com.biosensors"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-feature        
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"        
        android:required="true"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="bi.com.biosensors.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />  



         <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".BiMain"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

</activity>
        <activity android:name=".Products" >
</activity>
 <activity android:name=".ContactUs" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".WebMapViewActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".WebViewActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".openAccuActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".BusesNearby" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".openBiotransActivity" >
</activity>

<activity android:name=".openMultiLuActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".openThermoActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".openBiotrayActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".openBipolarActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".openEmboActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".openBioflexActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".openAxxessActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".openGazelleActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".openPowerlActivity" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".AlertCaution" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".BusRoutes" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".AllBuses" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".bus5route" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".bus15route" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".bus58route" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".bus59route" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".bus87route" >
            </activity>
               <activity android:name=".mrtMap" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
               </activity>
               <meta-data    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyCFLLz6m3N1WEKNG6KnwvoQvMBTC4r9AzA"/>
          </application>
    </manifest>
```

And my xml(Im pretty sure I have the right API key):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="***************"
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and my java code :

```
 public class WebMapViewActivity extends MapActivity {

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
        getActionBar();
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode);
        actionBar.setTitle("Map");

 MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

 List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
 Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
 GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(133339,-10390584);
 OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello!","This is Biosensors Interventional Singapore !");

 itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
 MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
 mapController.setCenter(point);

 mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
 }
 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
 {
 return false;
 }

        }
```

Comment: What is your goal then?

Comment: Well, sorry to tell you, but tiles are usually the consequences of having a wrong API key. Maybe it expired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidBriggs said you are mixing codes from API V1 and V2.

If you want to use Google Maps API V2 as it looks by all your manifest configuration then here is a blog post I wrote on how to add:

[Google Map API V2 to your App.](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you're mixing API v1 and v2 in this code.

In your layout remove the mapview and add this:

```
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

And extend Activity not MapActivity (or FragmentActivity if you're using the support library).

You can see some more info at the [Maps API page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)